# Jquery gmap3 variable for the zoom value not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-gmap3

With gmap3, I can put a "variable" for latitude and longitude, but for the "zoom" it's impossible.

```
var latitude = $('#lat_Value').text(); 
var longitude = $('#long_Value').text(); 
var mapZoom = $('#zoom_Value').text(); 

$("#map1").gmap3({

    marker:{ latLng:[latitude, longitude] },

    map:{
      options:{
        zoom: 16, // This is working...
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
      }
    }  
});

$("#map2").gmap3({

    marker:{ latLng:[latitude, longitude] },

    map:{
      options:{
        zoom: mapZoom, // This doesn't works !!..Why?
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
      }
    }  
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/d4CEY/) an exemple with two maps : the first map, with a number for the "zoom value" (it's working), and the second map with a variable for the "zoom value" (it doesn't work !).
What's the problem ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The value is a text value and somehow that must be the reason why its not working. Try parseInt() on the value.

```
var mapZoom = parseInt($('#zoom_Value').text());
```